# Why does a function print the value of a local auto variable from a function called earlier?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    int a=42;
}

void boo(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    boo();
}
```

Why does `boo` print the value of `a` from `foo`? I read an explanation about the execution stack and activation frames but I do not understand it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined behavior.

Comment: In function `boo`, variable `a` is uninitialized.  So it gets a random value.  Is 42 not random enough for you? :-)

Comment: @M.M thanks ı will be reading this now.

Comment: Local ("automatic" duration) variables are typically stored on the stack, which gets reused by each new function that's called.  So function `boo` gets a stack frame on the part of the stack formerly occupied by function `foo`'s  stack frame, and so uninitialized variables in function `boo` typically receive whatever random value was left there by function `foo`.  Sometimes, that's even a "reasonable" looking value.  In this case, since functions `foo` and `boo` both have exactly one local variable, their stack frame layouts end up being nearly identical.

Comment: @SteveSummit https://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c/137-include_stdioh_cc_O_fooc here you can see , just go ahead and you will see that the same program is being complied  in a different way and the result changes. what does cc -0 make so that the result changes ?

Comment: @user9679818: Undefined behaviour means any result is acceptable — and changes to options etc can change what's printed and its right both ways (or, more accurately, equally wrong both ways).  Simply don't do it.  Don't expect uninitialized variables to hold any specific value — the value can change at any time, for any reason.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I prefer to say it gets an *arbitrary* value rather than a random one. "Random" places too many (implicit) constraints on a novice's expectations.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you for answer this is enough for me to understand but guess it is  better to read what M.M refer to .

Comment: @user - As the slides talk about "different results for other compilers", this is what my compiler displays: *"warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'a' used"* and *"fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed"*. And no executable produced.

Comment: @user9679818 Sorry, can't view that slide show, but that's okay.  Why do you want to know why it changes?  Does it matter?  Do you need it not to change? Do you need to predict how it will change?  Or is this just curiosity on your part?

Comment: @SteveSummit this is just curiosity :)

Comment: @user9679818  Oftentimes curiosity is a fine thing, sometimes it's misplaced.  On this issue it can go either way.  For me, it's like asking, "Yesterday I ran a red light and nothing happened.  Today I ran a red light and got hit by a red car.  Why?  And why didn't I get hit by a blue truck?"

Comment: @user9679818 On the other hand, yes, if you can figure out precisely how the stack frames are arranged, and how they move around under different compilation options, you might learn a lot about assembly language and stack frame layout, and it might even be useful knowledge -- but I can't help you with it, because I haven't worried about assembly language or stack frame layouts for many years.

Comment: @SteveSummit  thanks for the answers :)  same for those who answered this question.

Comment: @SteveSummit This makes tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) akin to ensuring that there's lots of red cars and blue trucks to hit you every time.

Comment: [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) is the  answer  to the _Ultimate Question_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your function is called<sup>(a)</sup>.

```
                   stack
---------------------------------      call             return
---------------------------------
               |                |
earlier frame  | earlier frame  |
               |                |
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
               |                |                     (5) pop old %ebp to %ebp
               |----------------|
caller's frame | func arguments | (1) push args
               |----------------|
               | return address | (2) push ret-addr   (6) reset %esp here
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
               | old %ebp       | (3) push old %ebp   (4) reset %esp = %ebp
               |----------------|     reset %ebp here
               |                |
callee's frame | local variables|
               |                |
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
```

When a function returns, the data in its frame may be kept. 
So, in your case, `boo()` used the same frame with old data of `foo()`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Nothing in the standard *guarantees* this, it's just the most likely explanation for your *particular* scenario.